# Does anyone know of a walkthrough or tutorial on how to set the plist for iOS 6?

Tags: ios6, background, plist, cllocation

I need to set the plist to allow CLLocation to update the current location in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you setup a geofence:

```
{
  self.manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  self.manager.delegate = self;

  CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

  location.latitude  = <some lat>;
  location.longitude = <some long>;

  [self.manager startMonitoringForRegion:
   [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter: location
                                           radius: 1.0
                                       identifier: @"someplace"]];
}
```

Then implement the delegate methods to respond appropriately:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{ NSLog (@"didEnterRegion"); }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{ NSLog (@"didExitRegion"); }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{ NSLog (@"monitoringDidFailForRegion"); }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{ NSLog (@"didStartMonitoringForRegion"); }
```

Comment: so I don't need to change anything in the plist?

Comment: Yeah but when I would go to the plist to change something it wasn't there. I'm not sure if it was an older iOS or what

Comment: I just tested it; seemingly works.  Maybe you looked here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/